# Perforce - RpcTransport: partial message read

Tags: performance, perforce, p4v

When using "revert -a" through P4V it waits for a few minutes and throws this error back at me.

RpcTransport: partial message read
TCP receive failed.
read: socket: WSAECONNRESET

The server status returns fine and there are no locked database files.

I suspect this problem is local to this computer as others don't have the same issue. Issueing the same command through the command prompt just has the command prompt sit there indefinitly.

Other commands such as submit and add will have the visual client sit there indefinitely but does not throw and error.

The files are stored on a local drive. This happens with multiply depots/workstations.

Comment: Could it be your Windows firewall stopping you from connecting to the server?

Comment: I've ensured that P4V is set correctly in the firewall as well as just disabling it altogether. I've also made sure the ports are set right on the router and the MTU is set high enough.

I've contacted perforce support (they've replied quite quickly xD) and hopefully that will yield something. It's certainly something on my network though.

Comment: After factory resetting my router for a seperate reason, this problem went away for a week and has now returned. Still problem solving.

Comment: Yes, network disruption can be very frustrating to diagnose. I've seen problems due to TCP acceleration features, firewall policies, buffering, scaling, and MTU customization, etc. There are many sophisticated settings in modern network devices and lots of experiments that you may need to try to see if you can identify which one is disturbing the connection. Good luck and let us know what you find!

Answer (score 2):

The 'WSAECONNRESET' error is issued by Windows, when a network socket is forcibly closed.

Regular occurrences of this error can indicate network problems.

More information is available here:

http://answers.perforce.com/articles/KB/2968/

Hope this helps,
Jen!

Comment: I'll also leave this here as it is a good indiction that this error hasn't anything to do with ports.

`This error should not be confused with WSAECONNREFUSED where a port is blocked or a hostname is not set, nor WSAECONNABORT which is a more serious, harder-to-debug error caused by a connection which was halted by the local operating system after network packets were lost or a suitable acknowledgement signal (ACK) was not received.`

Answer (score 2):

I got the same on windows machine. I guess in my case it was caused by corrupted config settings and because of popup error message I had no chance to set it correctly via GUI.
The command line SET command helped to set port and host name again:

```
p4 set P4PORT=<portnum>
```

This command reenables the GUI config dialog

Answer (score 0):

A few years late, but for those still facing this:

I faced this error when fetching files from a large repo. I believe what caused this for me was low internet upload speeds due to which - even though I had high a download speed - the TCP acknowledgment from my computer was not getting sent, causing a connection failure.

Perform an upload speed test to determine if it is very low (in my case it had dropped to less than 0.1 Mbps). Fixing upload speeds is a separate topic, but in case it helps try restarting your router as a first step.